# Android Bitmap to Byte Array per Pixel conversion

Tags: android, bitmap, pdf-generation, jpeg

I'm confused about a decoding bitmap to `ByteOutputStream`

I'm using android Library apw - android pdf writer which uses a method to convert bitmap to byte[] array.

I'm trying to achieve this using toByteArray() method but the output pdf shows a black image instead.

library approach

```
 private byte[] getBitmapData(Bitmap bitmap) {
        byte[] data = null;
        if (bitmap != null) {
            data = new byte[mDataSize];
            int intColor;
            int offset = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < mHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < mWidth; x++) {
                    intColor = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                    data[offset++] = (byte) ((intColor >> 16) & 0xFF);
                    data[offset++] = (byte) ((intColor >> 8) & 0xFF);
                    data[offset++] = (byte) ((intColor >> 0) & 0xFF);
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

My new approach

```
private byte[] getBitmapData(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm inexperienced in bitwise logic and conversation.
I couldn't exactly understand the library method.

Is there something am i missing here?
A little help will be appreciated

Comment: Could you clarify -- what is wrong with the library method? And which of the two methods doesn't work? What are you trying to do with the output from `getBitmapData()`?

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the output pdf size by compressing the images.

Comment: The library only supports bitmap for adding images. For a small pdf file size, when a compressed bitmap is loaded from file it no longer is compressed. So I want to manually compress bitmap to bytearrayoutputstream and supply to the calling method (replacing library method with my custom method). AFAIK The library method processes each pixel takes r, g,b component and adds to stream. My method wont work (displayes some noise and black image) because the stream.tobytearray() returns alpha values too?

Comment: As stated i'm just  replacing library method  implementation in  source code with my own implementation. Library method works well  but using compressed bitmaps instead of original ones is of no use because of this library method responsible to ?decode image? which i guess does not respect bitmap compression. I want to reduce the byte[] array size ultimately reducing  image size and pdf size. Hence my approach is to develop a method which respects bitmap compression. Or is it not related to android but jpeg? If so how appa like camscanner compresses high quality images in less size?

Comment: Here's the source code and method I'm mentioning. https://github.com/Turbo87/apwlibrary/blob/master/apwlibrary/src/main/java/crl/android/pdfwriter/XObjectImage.java

Comment: I see; you're forking a .pdf writer library, and it writes out images as bitmaps, but you want to make them .jpgs in order to save space. It doesn't sound like you changed the behavior of `appendToDocument()`, though; you just plugged in .jpg data where it was expecting RGB data. Check [ISO 32000](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) and search for "DCTDecode"; that's what you're supposed to use for .jpg.

Comment: i am unable to fully understand the encoding - decoding part.Tried replacing ASCII85Decode with DCTDecode but not working (blank white page).I can't figure out how to extract rgb data from the byte[] stream.A bit more explanation?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a pdf expert. I added the "pdf-generation" tag to your question so it might attract the right people. I can tell you that you must follow the spec in order to get this to work. You could try googling for DCTDecode examples. But you don't need to worry about RGB data anymore. That's what version 1 of `getBitmapData()` did. Version 2 -- your version -- should be giving you the correct data to use with DCTDecode.